# Deploy time Webservice location

Tags: vb.net, web-services, url, vs-web-application-project

In my Visual Studio Web application project I am adding a reference to a web service. When I add a web reference the following list of files gets generated.

- Reference.map
- Reference.vb
- Reference.disco
- Reference.wsdl

All these files contains the url pointing to the web service. Even when I move it to a machine without visual studio, it works fine. But if I intend to change the url of the web service, I need to modify *all these four files* by editing them using notepad.

Instead of this, is there any way I can have the url in the config file and just change it in one place and the web service are pointed to the new location.

I am using framework 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the web service reference "Url Behaviour" property to Dynamic, and the address will be cofigured in your app.config file....

The app.config file should then contain something like

```
    <applicationSettings>
        <Exceptions.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Exceptions_CentreService_CentreService" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://localhost/CentreServiceCompatibility/CentreService.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </Exceptions.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
```